# Slow SSD speed of MacBook Air 2015

Tags: ssd, performance, macbook-air

My MacBook Air is really slow, beachballing a lot.

Tested write speed of about 200 MB/s with Transcend JetDrive 820 (1TB), while it was about 600 MB/s with the original one (128GB).
In order to get these results, I use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=xxx bs=100k count=1k && sync
```

I noticed that reported JetDrive connectivity is AHCI PCIe x1 (while advertised at x2).

The original SSD reports AHCI PCIe x4.

Would that explain the problem? Would that be a hardware failure of JetDrive 820?

Comment: Is that Transcend JetDrive 820 (1GB)? You mean, 1TB correct?

Comment: This looks like the expected speed for a PCIe x1 connectivity. I would return the drive to the vendor.